# R: how to get prediction interval from gbm?

Tags: r, prediction, confidence-interval, gbm

I am running a boosted regression tree using the `gbm` package in R but can't figure out how to get the prediction interval. I have 10 features, and I would like to vary the value of value of one feature `X1` (which takes on 4 discrete values: `A, B, C, D`) to see if the predicted value `Y` (dependent variable) is significantly different among the 4 discrete values (while holding the other `9` features constant). For example, is `A` associated with higher predicted value than `B` at a `5%` level while holding all other features constant

Does anyone have any code they can share to calculate the prediction interval in R?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the caret package function "train()". But first a training data set need to be there so we can do that by using "createDataPartition()" function and then create training and testing data set, then train the model using training data set and predict for testing data set and then validate with "confusionmatrix()" function

```
data<-data #contains the data of 10 variables 
intrain<- createDataPartition(y = data$X1, p = 0.8, list = F)
training<- data[intrain,]
testing<- data[-intrain,]

relation<- train(form = X1~., data = training, method = "gbm")
result<- predict(relation, testing)

confusionMatrix(testing$X1, result)
```

Hope this resolve your query

Comment: I looked over the documentation for train() and did not see an option for the prediction interval (for example, the 95% prediction interval). Can you be more specific as to how to use this function to get the prediction interval?

Comment: It will give you the forecasting value in between 80% to 95% confidence interval